# Realm 0.89 causes UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: android, realm

Since upgrading from Realm 0.83.1 to 0.85 or 0.89, I'm unable to run the app. So I'm stuck in 0.83.1 version. I'm getting this weird link error when I run on the device. I'm trying to encrypt the database, but it's only fully supported in 0.85 or higher. Any help would be appreciated!

Here is my Logcat output:
    Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for java.lang.String io.realm.internal.Util.nativeGetTablePrefix() 
       (tried Java_io_realm_internal_Util_nativeGetTablePrefix and 
              Java_io_realm_internal_Util_nativeGetTablePrefix__)
    at io.realm.internal.Util.nativeGetTablePrefix(Native Method)
    at io.realm.internal.Util.getTablePrefix(Util.java:47)
    at io.realm.internal.Table.(Table.java:38)
    at io.realm.RealmSchema.(RealmSchema.java:40)
    at io.realm.BaseRealm.(BaseRealm.java:78)
    at io.realm.Realm.(Realm.java:138)
    at io.realm.Realm.createAndValidate(Realm.java:269)
    at io.realm.Realm.createInstance(Realm.java:249)
    at io.realm.RealmCache.createRealmOrGetFromCache(RealmCache.java:114)
    at io.realm.Realm.getDefaultInstance(Realm.java:195)

I tried creating an empty project and it seems to work fine, but it doesn't work on my real project. I suspect an issue with multi-dex, but I ran it on a phone with Android M and it failed the same way.

Comment: You need to apply the realm-android plugin by instructions here https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#getting-started and you need to remove the `compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.xx.x'` from the gradle. Also try to clean the project and build. :)

Comment: Do you a custom dependency in your project? Or maybe any dependency that includes Realm?

Answer (score 2):

0.88.0 has changed the way of adding Realm as a dependency. So instead of:

- build.gradle (app level)

.

```
 dependencies {
     compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.87.4'
 }
```

You have to do:

- build.gradle (app level)

.

```
apply-plugin: 'realm-android'
```

- build.gradle (project level)

.

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
         classpath 'io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:0.89.0'
    }
}
```